# Increment a variable by 3 in a loop that increments by 1

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, operators, increment

I want to create a loop where the "i" variable is incrementing by one (i++), and I want to add another variable "j" in the loop that increment not by one but 3 per 3 (so j+=3, and then the output looks like 0, 3, 6, 9, 12...).

I have tried so many thing, but here is my code that looks logic :

```js
let j;

for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  j = i += 3;
  console.log(j); //It increments by 4, WTF ??
  console.log(i); //Exactly the same whereas i should increments per 1
}
```

I also tried to create a variable "k" that is equal to "i" to leave "i" alone, but still doesn't work.

Thank you so much for your help guys :)

PS : Once solved, do you know how to make the variable j starts by 0 please ?

Comment: `i++` increase the number by 1 in every iteration. If you just want to increament `j`, use `let j = 0` and `j += 3;` inside the loop

Comment: `+=` is an addition assignment (hence i changing value). `j = i + 3` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
let j=0;

for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  j+=3
  console.log(j); //starts at 3, because in the first line of the function we say j = 0 + 3, so j=3, then once it loops again it gets +3 again, so it's 6 and so on.
  console.log(i); //just increments by 1 each loop
```

Try this, is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ! Thanks ! And I have set j to -3 to start by 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this - you can use comma separators in the initiator and loop  statements in the for statement

```js
for (let i = 0, j = 1; i < 24; i++, j += 3) {
  console.log("i",i,"j",j);
}
```

Comment: Amazing ! I didn't know you can set multiple variables in the loop ! Thanks !